# When send Exception message to developer with SMS, is it OK to use 'e.toString()'

Tags: exception

When Exception occured, I want to send Exception message to developer by SMS. 
Is it OK to send 'e.toString()' >?

I have tested few times, the String length was not much long. 
so I choose 'e.toString()' is it OK?

could you recommend me the better way?

```
    try {
         ...
    }  catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        SmsVo smsVo = new SmsVo();
        smsVo.setRecPhoneNum(rb.getString("phNumForCheck"));
        // send 
        sendSmsSttcAllDownRslt(smsVo, e.toString(), dateStr);
    }
```